pgfplots discrepancy between "nodes at coords" and "text mark" in parsing point meta
I'm plotting a relatively small matrix where I want to display the value of each cell in addition to the color. This works great when using nodes near coords, but this shifts the text upwards.
I'd love to reuse this plot type for slightly different matrices and would prefer not to have to adjust the downward shift every time, so instead I tried using the values as text mark. But in that case the point meta is not right. Is there a way to fix this, or should I just shift the nodes downwards?
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false]
        \addplot [
            matrix plot,
            %This works, except for the vertical offset
            nodes near coords = {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision = 2]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
            mesh/cols=2,
            point meta=explicit,
        ] table [point meta=\thisrow{C}] {
            x y C
            1 0 0
            2 0 1
            1 1 3
            2 1 4
            1 2 6
            2 2 7
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false]
        \addplot [
            matrix plot,
            mark = text,
            text mark = {
            %but here, the same command does not have access to the correct point meta?
            \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision = 2]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
            },
            mesh/cols=2,
            point meta=explicit,
        ] table [point meta=\thisrow{C}] {
            x y C
            0 0 0
            1 0 1
            0 1 3
            1 1 4
            0 2 6
            1 2 7
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Welcome to TeX.SX!

Use simply
nodes near coords style={anchor=center},

Example:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false]
    \addplot [
      matrix plot,
      nodes near coords = {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision = 2]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
      nodes near coords style={anchor=center},
      mesh/cols=2,
      point meta=explicit,
    ] table [point meta=\thisrow{C}] {
      x y C
      1 0 0
      2 0 1
      1 1 3
      2 1 4
      1 2 6
      2 2 7
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



that's what you get for focusing on a specific solution, guess there's no need to worry about text marks at all. thanks!
